# Sort Array after closest Solution

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an unsorted array with results of an calculation:

```
const solution = 955

const unsortedArray = 
[
  [["solution result cab"],[955.709]],
  [["solution result abc"],[951.11]],
  [["solution result cba"],[954.709]],
  [["solution result bac"],[957.709]]
]
```

I want to sort the array after +/- the closest deviation of the solution:

```
[
  [["solution result cab"],[955.709]],
  [["solution result cba"],[954.709]],
  [["solution result bac"],[957.709]],
  [["solution result abc"],[951.11]]
]
```

Is there some way to apply a range comparison into `sort()` or is there a better solution?

Comment: Have you tried creating your own `Comparator` function ? If yes, do post your attempt and what is issue you are facing.
A hint would be that you can check how (num1 - solution) compares to (num2 - solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a compare function that will compare the two elements' absolute differences from the solution. A positive number means the first element is bigger. A negative one means the second is bigger.

```
function compare(a, b) {
  const aAbs = Math.abs(a[1][0] - solution);
  const bAbs = Math.abs(b[1][0] - solution);
  return aAbs - bAbs;
}
```

Then you can run `unsortedArray.sort(compare)`.

Comment: `a[1]` -> `a[1][0]` and the same with `b`.

Answer (score 2):

Per [the documentation of Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#parameters), you can supply a sorting function:

```js
const compareDeviationFrom = (solution) => {
  (resA, resB) => Math.abs(resA[1][0] - solution) - Math.abs(resB[1][0] - solution)
}

unsortedArray.sort(compareDeviationFrom(solution))
```